# Python/Pandas; split elements

Tags: python, dataframe, split

I have a Pandas DataFrame with a column like this:

| index | ID | Value_1 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 123 |
| 2 | 2 | 543;735;926 |
| 3 | 3 | 64;235 |
| 4 | 4 | 7643 |

Is there a way to build a column like this:

| index | ID | Value_2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 123 |
| 2 | 2 | 543 |
| 3 | 2 | 735 |
| 4 | 2 | 926 |
| 5 | 3 | 64 |
| 6 | 3 | 235 |
| 7 | 4 | 7643 |

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `str.explode`

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([[1,'123'], [2, '543;735;926'], [3, '64;235'], [4, '7643']], columns=['ID', 'Value_1'])

df['Value_1'] = df['Value_1'].str.split(';')

df.explode('Value_1')
```

```
    ID  Value_1
0   1   123
1   2   543
1   2   735
1   2   926
2   3   64
2   3   235
3   4   7643
```

Comment: Thank You! My actual task is to get this values out in a loop for further calculations. Is there a elegant way do to this if the elements 'sometimes' separated with a semicolon like in the fist table (Value_1)?

Comment: Check the answer, are you looking for this?

Comment: Sorry my question was imprecise. I have modified the two tables above. So e.g. the 'Value_1' with the index 2 have the same ID. After the explode() they shoud keep their IDs like in the second table. Thank you for your help!

Comment: @David1989 check the answer

Answer (score 0):

Just `split` on `;` and `explode`:

```py
df['Value_1'].str.split(';').explode()
```

**OUTPUT:**

```py
0     123
1     543
1     735
1     926
2      64
2     235
3    7643
Name: Value_1, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that your input column data is all strings.
In that case you can split every string and chain the resulting iterators

```py
import itertools

def split_column(column, sep: str = ";"):
  return itertools.chain.from_iterable(
    map(lambda s: s.split(sep), column)
  )
```

This should replicate your example request

```py
import pandas as pd
import itertools

ds = pd.DataFrame(data={
  "Value_1": [
    "123",
    "543;735;926",
    "64;235",
    "7643"
  ]
})

def split_column(column, sep: str = ";"):
  return itertools.chain.from_iterable(
    map(lambda s: s.split(sep), column)
  )

ds2 = pd.DataFrame(data={"Value_2": split_column(ds["Value_1"])})
```

If I print `ds` I get

```
       Value_1
0          123
1  543;735;926
2       64;235
3         7643
```

If I print `ds2` I get

```
  Value_2
0     123
1     543
2     735
3     926
4      64
5     235
6    7643
```